# Проблема в кодировке UrlEncode

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой в кодировке UrlEncode. Я закодировал русские символы с помощью UrlEncode и вывожу полностью ссылку в Debug:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С виду все отлично, но когда перехожу по ссылке json пустой в самом Visual Studio, а на любом браузере json заполнен. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему в Visual Studio возвращает пустой json не могу понять?

Comment: А почему вы делаете UrlEncode только для части строки? Вам не надо кодировать _всю_ строку?

Comment: В той части строки присутствуют два проблемы, когда делаю UrlEncode, он кодирует текст и заместо этих пробелов ставит плюсы. В остальных частях строк нет смысла кодировать так как в них нет пробелов и они берутся как уже готовые строки.

Comment: Хм. То, что там проблем нет, не означает, что ту часть не надо кодировать. Попробуйте закодировать всё вместе всё же.

Comment: Я закодировал и в итоге вышла такая строка: http%3A%2F%2Fmagtu.ru%2Fmodules%2Fmod_reiting_bel%2Fmobile2.php%3Faction%3Dget_reiting_abit%26fio%3D%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%26spec_kod%3D22.03.020

Comment: У меня такой вопрос. Почему он в Visual Studio url-адрес возвращает текст "Казанцева+Виктория+Игоревна", а не показывает в таком ввиде "%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0" ?

Comment: Ну это смотря как вы его получаете. Дайте ваш код.

Comment: `private async Task GetAllSpecialtyAndEntrants(BranchBeloretskBudgetItemsViewCell Item){
   var id = Item.id;
            
   IdEntrant = WebUtility.UrlEncode(id); // Коидруем строку
   var URLInfoEntrants = URLBudgetBranchBeloretskInfoEntrant + IdEntrant + URLBudgetBranchBeloretskSpecKod + IdSpecialty; // создаем целую ссылку
                
   Debug.WriteLine("URL: " + URLInfoEntrants);
   var response = await get(URLInfoEntrants).Result;
}

static public async Task<string> get(string url)
{
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
}`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь не хватало следующих строк кода
`if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}`

Вопрос закрыт!!!